# Strange behaviour in LINQPad with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, linqpad, nsubstitute

I wrote the following sample in LINQPad 4 (`v.4.57.02`) to demonstrate the folly of trying to use NSubstitute (`v1.9.2.0`) to mock a type and it's non-virtual property:

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = Substitute.For<Foo>();
    foo.Alarm.Returns(2);    
    foo.Alarm.Dump();
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo ctor called.");
    }

    public virtual int Alarm
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

This code works as expected and gives the following output:

```
Foo ctor called.
2
```

Now, when I edit the code to remove the `virtual` modifier on the `Alarm` property, I am expecting to see an `NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToNoLastCallException` exception which includes the wisdom:

> If you substituted for a class rather than an interface, check that the call to your substitute was on a virtual/abstract member. Return values cannot be configured for non-virtual/non-abstract members.

However, the *first* time I run the modified code I get:

```
Foo ctor called.
0
```

And on subsequent runs I get the expected exception.

Now I suspect there's something funny going on with the way that LINQPad manages AppDomains and how NSubstitute's Castle proxies work - but I don't know what. Hands up, I just don't have the time to dig too far into this, and wondered if anyone else has a definitive explanation as it would be comforting to know about the gotchas in the LINQPad execution environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start open a new instance of LINQPad and run the code without the `virtual` member it will fail straight away with the expected error.

So here is my guess as to what is happening. The first time the code is run with the `virtual` member NSubstitute's state looks like this:

```
var foo = Substitute.For<Foo>();
foo.Alarm         // 1. last call is foo.Alarm
   .Returns(2);   // 2. make foo.Alarm return `2`. Clear last call.
foo.Alarm         // 3. last call is foo.Alarm
   .Dump();       // 4. extension method -- doesn't clear last call
```

NSubstitute stores the last call made to a substitute statically, so it hangs around until the appdomain goes away. When you modify the code to remove the `virtual` and run it again, the `.Returns(2)` in step 2 finds the last call made in step 3 of the previous run, stubs it accordingly, then clears the last call. No further calls are recorded due to the non-virtual member, so subsequent runs fail with the expected error.

Comment: That certainly makes a lot of sense. Nice one.

Comment: Also, important to note that the call from the previous run was on another instance of the stubbed object, which means that the `.Returns(2)` call was made on an object no longer reachable from your LINQPad code, but was reachable from the static storage of the "last call" concept in NSubstitute.